# How to show tags in a textarea

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to show tags in a textarea in my react app like this:
[image]
The user should be able to add his own tags to the textarea. I can't figure out how to do it without creating XSS vulnerabilities. Does anyone know what the best way to do this is?

Comment: textarea are meant to have plain text. Probably you wish to rely on [contenteditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable)

Comment: Probably you need to create a div with contenteditable set as true, and then append spans for the breadcrumb elements

Answer (score 0):

Your question was not clear to me, however there are 2 different possibilities for the question and here we have the answers.

1. If you want your user to add/update the existing text/content, go with **contenteditable**
2. If you want your user to have flexibility of editing not only just content, also able to add, style the content then go with **code editors** there are plenty of code editors and you can pick one among them based on your use case.

Hope this helps!